# Is there environment variable for Extension parent app target name

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-extensions

I wish to set the extension Bundle identifier by script according to its parent App. (So I can reuse the extension without duplicating the extension target.

right now the extension is hardcoded to this -

```
com.XXXXXX.FirstTargetName.QOD-Notification-Extention
```

I wish to create a script that will run when building the extension and set the bundle identifier dynamically to other target names.

Is there any environment variable that I can reach to get the parent app target name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No** (not till `Xcode 12`, but maybe they add one in newer Xcode versions?!).
See also: [How to load prefix set by parent project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69007621/8740349)

---

Longer answer:
Having the same issue, I looked at all the environment variables available to a script which I'm trying to use. I did not find the parent target's name or anything that provided a clue to the parent's name in those variables. I'm hoping I missed something.

To get a full list of environment variables I looked at the excellent suggestions here: [How do I print a list of “Build Settings” in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project/36213785#36213785)

but ultimately I used the suggestion here: [Running Bash Script on XCode Compile — Where To Get List of Build Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098032/running-bash-script-on-xcode-compile-where-to-get-list-of-build-variables/35098135)